# Background and hover effect

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I'm trying to make the above text (home help customer etc) similar to the one below `Home` and all in green box with white text and `hover` effect but I am unable to add the green `background` and make the words display similar to the once below with a `hover` effect I have tried some things out but it did not help me out and also I have tried a lot to move the cart to the top right to make it look like a normal shopping website but it didn't work if you guys see any mistakes or suggestions to make it better I would really appreciate it as I am a beginner  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT1r1.jpg

Help fix the top `header` please refer the image link as it shows were exactly is the green box and all thank you[the image has the header of the website were there are different buttons like guest customer help etc and I am trying to make it like the one underneath in the green box with a hover effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SUya.png)

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Rajeshri Traders </title>
  <link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="subheader">
        <div class="container">
          <p> CCTV Supplier</p>
          <a href="#">Guest </a><a href="#">Consumer </a><a href="#">Download App </a>
          <a href="#">Help </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--==main header==-->
      <div id="main-header">
        <!--logo-->
        <div id="logo">
          <span id="ist"></span><span id="iist"> Rajshri  Traders</span>
        </div>
        <!--==search area==-->
        <div id="search">
          <form action="">
          </form>
          <input class="search-area" type="text" placeholder="Search here">
          <input class="search-btn" type="submit" value="SEARCH">
          <!--="user-menu"==-->
          <div id="user menu">
          </div>
          <li><a href="#">Cart</a>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!----=====navigation bar==--->
    <div id="navigation">
      <nav>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">New Arrivals</a>
        <a href="#">Products</a>
        <a href="#">Deals</a>
        <a href="#">Accesories</a>
        <a href="#">Order</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  font-family: tahoma;
}


/*logo styling*/

#main-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 125px;
  background: #93A7FF;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
}

#main-header > div {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

#ist {
  color: black;
  font-size: 65px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-family: fantasy;
}

#iist {
  color: black;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-family: fantasy;
}


/*searchinga area styling*/

#search {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.search-area {
  width: 350px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.search-btn {
 width: 65px;
  height: 34px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: brown;
  margin-left: 15px;
}


/*this is for user menu styling*/

#user-menu {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: right; 
}

#unser-menu ul {
 list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
}

#user-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

#main-header > div {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}


/*this style is for navigation bar */
#navigation{
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
background: #1aaa1a;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 10px 14px 45px 3px #1aaa1a;

}
nav{
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;    
}
nav a{
    margin-left: 35px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;

}
nav a:hover{
    color:#000;
    transition: all .7s ease; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To give a background colour to your 'home, help, customer etc' text, you need to refer to the element in which they are all included. In this case, they are all contained within the `.container class`. So by adding styling to the `.container` class, you'll be adding styling to the div containing the text in question.

Simply add a background colour to the `.container` class like this:

`.container {
  background: #1aaa1a;
}`

As for the hover effect, you can specify the effect you want for each link of the 'home, help, container etc'. For example, if you want to change the colour of the text when you hover on it, you can do something like this

`.container a:hover {
   color: black;
}`

The `.container a` is how you reference the links contained in your `.container` class.

Comment: hey thanks, it works but I am still figuring on how to make it look like the one shown in the green box below text is white and the allignment I don't know how to do it please help https://imgur.com/2Bhxzs2 (home new arrivals etc)

Comment: See my most recent answer

Answer (score 1):

Alright.So you need to see what styling you have applied to the text in the green box. you need to copy the styling you use in #navigation which is the container for everything in the green box. You have included your links in the green box in a nav element, you have then styled the nav element as follows:

```
nav{
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;    
}
nav a{
    margin-left: 35px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;

}
nav a:hover{
    color:#000;
    transition: all .7s ease; 
}
```

You need to style your links in the .container div in the same way. The easiest way to do this would be to include your home, help, customer links in a nav element as follows:

```
<div class="container">
  <p> CCTV Supplier</p>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Guest </a><a href="#">Consumer </a>                           
    <a href="#">Download App </a>
    <a href="#">Help </a>
  </nav>
</div>
```